# In what sense is a polynomial not a power series?

Tags: power-series

Little confusion on my part.  I am reading wiki to learn power series and it says " a polynomial can easily be expressed as a power series..."  and "one can view power series as being like polynomials of infinite degree ..."   and "although power series are not polynomials..."   . The quotation marks are what I printed directly from wiki.

My confusion is in what sense are they not?  Since I can take any polynomial and express it as power series.

Comment: A polynomial has a finite number of terms (monomials). A power series can have a monomial in each degree. Example: the *geometric series*: $1+x+x^2+\dots+x^n+\dots=\sum_{n\ge 0}x^n$.

Comment: `although power series are not polynomials` Read this more carefully. It does *not* say or imply that polynomials are not power series, which your title seems to be asking.

Comment: you are correct.  it should be in what sense is a power series not a polynomial ......

Comment: I am confusing polynomial vs.polynomial function.  and also if a power series does not converge then perhaps it cannot be defined as a function so there you have a case that the power series is not even a function.

Comment: Nowhere do they say that "a polynomial [is] not a power series" so, why the title (and the whole post, actually)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A more correct sentence can reconcile these views: "although *in general* power series are not polynomials..."

All polynomials are (finite) power series, not all power series are polynomials.

Answer (score 2):

Polynomials are power series with almost all coefficients vanishing. Have a look at exponential function: $$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}.$$ Is it really a polynomial?

Comment: @RobArthan: agreed, discarding my comment.

Answer (score 2):

A polynomial of degree n stops at the $n^{th}$ power of x. For example a third degree polynomial is $$ P(x) = a_0 +a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + a_3 x^3 $$ 
A Power series on the other hand can go for ever.

For example the  power series for $e^x$ is indeed an infinite series which does not stop at any degree.

A power series is not necessarily a polynomial unless from some point on all the coefficients are zero.

A polynomial can be considered a power series whose coefficients are zero from some point on.